# Guard-Less won't respect output parameter

Tags: ruby, sinatra, less, guard

I just started my first Sinatra app, and I'm trying to get [Guard-Less](https://github.com/guard/guard-less) up and running. I already fixed an [rb-readline issue](https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/357) which was preventing changes to the .less file from updating my CSS, but I'm also unable to get the compiled CSS file output into the correct directory. Guard-Less says you can pass an `:output` option to guard to ensure the CSS is compiled to the correct directory, but I haven't gotten this to work once yet. The CSS just compiles to the same directory as the LESS file.

I'm running the app with `foreman start` locally.

Guardfile:

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme

guard 'less', 
  :all_on_start => true,
  :output => 'public/assets/css' do
  watch(%r{^less/(.+\.less)$})
end
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'shotgun'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'rb-readline'
gem 'less', '~>1.2'
gem 'haml'
gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9'
gem 'guard-less'
```

Procfile:

```
guard: bundle exec guard
web: bundle exec ruby bootstrap.rb -p $PORT
```

bootstrap.rb file:

```
require 'rubygems'  
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'haml'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base

  get '/' do  
    haml :index
  end

end

MyApp.run!
```

The output of `guard show` proves the option is being recognized:

```
$ guard show
+---------+--------+--------+-----------------------+
| Group   | Plugin | Option | Value                 |
+---------+--------+--------+-----------------------+
| Default | Less   | output | "public/assets/css"   |
+---------+--------+--------+-----------------------+
```

Worst comes to worst I can just leave the .less files in the same directory as my output css, but this is annoying me and I'd like to get it working. Any ideas?